# An order relation on the real numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let $\Bbb R$ be the set of real numbers. For $x, y \in \Bbb R$, $x \sim y$ iff $x + y \in \Bbb Z$, i.e., if the sum $x + y$ is an integer. Determine:
(i) Whether or not the relation $\sim$ is reflexive;
(ii) Whether or not the relation $\sim$ is symmetric;
(iii) Whether or not the relation $\sim$ is anti-symmetric;
(iv) Whether or not the relation $\sim$ is transitive;
(v) Whether or not the relation $\sim$ is an equivalence relation;
(vi) Whether or not the relation $\sim$ is a partial order.
Justify answers.

I understand the concepts but I am unsure on how to answer with wording and justify the answers correctly.

Comment: You should show us what you would do, so that we can tell you if you're doing ok.

Comment: (i) Is reflexive, x E R, x + x = 2x . Since 2x is divisible by 2 for any integer x, we may conclude that (x,x) E R for any integer x, which is to say that R is reflexive

Comment: *Hint:*  Some of the infinitely many pairs in the relation are things such as $(0.1, 0.9)$ (*because $0.1+0.9=1$ is an integer*), such as $(\sqrt{2}+15, -\sqrt{2}+3)$ (*because $\sqrt{2}+15+(-\sqrt{2})+3 = 18$ is an integer*) and so on.  Is $0.1$ related to itself?  If $x+y$ is an integer does it follow that $y+x$ is an integer?  If you have $x+y$ is an integer and $y+z$ is an integer does that imply that $x+z$ is an integer?  $0.1+0.9$ is an integer and $0.9+1.1$ is an integer but...

Comment: In your comment just now, you seem to have completely ignored that we are talking about a relation over the real numbers, not a relation merely over the integers.

Comment: I'm confused in relation on how to justify the answer, I understand now the 0.1 +0.9 = 1 is a integer and the symmetry part in terms of this example, however I don't understand the concept of how 0.1 can relate to itself

Comment: $0.1$ *doesn't* relate to itself.  That is the point.  And since we have an example of a number in our domain which doesn't relate to itself that means that it is not reflexive.

Comment: I encourage you once you finish with this particular problem to revisit it with the change that instead of looking at the relation $x\sim y$ iff $x+y\in\Bbb Z$ to look instead at the relation $x\approx y$ iff $x-y\in\Bbb Z$ where we replaced the addition with a subtraction instead.

Answer (score 3):

1) No the relation is not reflexive since $x+x$ may not be an integer (for a counter-example, just take $x=0.2$)

2) Yes it is symmetric since if $x\sim y$, it means $x+y$ is an integer. So, $y+x$ is also an integer. So, $y\sim x$

3) No it is not anti-symmetric since $0.5+1.5$ is integer but $0.5\neq 1.5$

4) No it is not transitive since $0.1+1.9$ is integer and $1.1+1.9$ is integer but $1.1+0.1$ is not an integer.

5) No since relation must be R-S-T for this

6) No since relation must be R-AS-T for this

Comment: `$~$` produces white space such as here: $~$.  `$\sim$` on the other hand produces $\sim$.

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you, I didn't notice/knew that!